# Script to fetch events/ID/name from an API, then list them, G-sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Guilded just (pre)released an API, and I wish to use it to retrieve the list of events, events's id, events's names from my server, and have it in a Google-sheet.
Next, I'll try to retrieve the members from the events.
I had a similar issue yesterday for the [server's members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373692/script-to-fetch-users-and-id-from-an-api-then-list-them-one-by-one-in-g-sheet), but I don't seem to understand how to read the data I'm pulling -_-'

I have a test file here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZUZ6utQO6cW_BAy6cMACxX2H1_zrZAIE0CTtTmdN9nc/edit?usp=sharing

​Thank you for any help you could provide,

Nyl,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I found your current script. When your current script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
let id = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.id.length; i++){
  
  name.push([data.id[0],data.id[0].name,data.id[i].startsAt]);
}

ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(10,4,id.length,2).setValues(id);
```

#### To:

```js
var values = data.calendarEvents.map(({ id, name, startsAt }) => [id, name, startsAt]);
ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(10, 4, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Aaron Raven, and you are not supposed to use `console.log` on server-side files, use `Logger.log` instead...